# Joining large tables in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, select, join

I have a table called "calls", there are columns:

```
a_imei_number
b_imei_number
a_phone_number
b_phone_number

call_start_time
call_end_time
```

if a specific phone called x calls y then imei number of x is in `a_imei_number` column if y calls x then imei of x in `b_imei_number`. Shortly difference between `a_imei_number` and `b_imei_number` is incoming and outgoing calls for an imei. same for phone_number columns.

I am searching calls for a specific imei that happen in same time (cloned imei numbers) so i thought if i find a call whose call_start_time between other's call_start_time and call_end_time then i would find the cloned phones. so imei numbers must be same and phone numbers must be different logically.

so i wrote

```
select * from calls c1 , calls c2 
where (c1.a_imei = 1234 or c1.b_imei = 1234) 
and 
c1.call_start_time between c2.call_start_time and c2.call_end_time
```

table has maybe 500M data. so this query is not returning and result maybe in 1 week it returns. Is there anyother way to find the result without joining same table like this ?

Comment: Which indexes are defined on the `calls` table? What is the execution plan of the query?

Comment: there is no index on that table. i don't understand what you mean 'execution plan', i want to find rows have same imei in a_imei or b_imei and call_start time of one of it is between the other one's times. is it impossible to find that without index in short time?

Comment: `Execution plan` is how `Oracle` will treat your query. It gives you hints on how to improve your query, after analysing it.

Comment: You are also not properly joining the tables

Comment: Your join is highly inefficient, you're linking all records in c1 to c2, using the proper join will help

Comment: then how can i write that query better instead of using linking c1 and c2 ?

Comment: You might want to consider detailing the expected results, the examples below all are "better" or more accurately "more efficient" than your query provided above. The sub-query approach is much better than my suggestion, each will (from what I can see) return the same results, if the results returned are incorrect examples and/or an SQL Fiddle (see http://www.sqlfiddle.com) would obviously be beneficial to anyone willing to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you are looking for calls that occur at the same time as calls to or from a specific number.  The following query expresses this idea:

```
select c2.*
from (select c.*
      from calls c
      where c.a_imei = 1234 or c.b_imei = 1234
     ) cbase join
     calls c2
     on cbase.call_start_time between c2.call_start_time and c2.call_end_time;
```

The performance is going to depend greatly on the number of matches of the first query.

Sometimes, the database engine has a hard time optimizing `or` in a condition.  I would suggest having indexes on `calls(a_imei, call_start_time)` and `calls(b_imei, call_start_time)` and rewriting the query as:

```
select c2.*
from ((select c.call_start_time
       from calls c
       where c.a_imei = 1234
      ) union all
      (select c.call_start_time
       from calls c
       where c.b_imei = 1234
      )
     ) cbase join
     calls c2
     on cbase.call_start_time between c2.call_start_time and c2.call_end_time;
```

For the final join, a third index would be useful:  `calls(call_start_time, call_end_time)`.

Comment: it is returning all rows because every calls' start time is between their own start time and end time. every row is returned as twice multiplied.

Comment: @abidinberkay . . . It returns all the *matching* calls because they meat the criteria in your question.  You don't explain exactly what you are looking for, so I used the logic in your queries.  If you don't want the original call, then exclude them.

Answer (score 1):

This probably won't help completely, but will hopefully give someone with more knowledge something to start with:

**Improving the join**

```
SELECT * 
FROM calls c1 
INNER JOIN calls c2 ON c1.call_start_time BETWEEN c2.call_start_time AND c2.call_end_time
WHERE (c1.a_imei = 1234 or c1.b_imei = 1234)
```

**Other Comments:**

`SELECT *` will be inefficient as it is, especially as it will be returning non unique column names, you should only select the columns relevant to the query in question.

Comment: it is returning all rows because every calls' start time is between their own start time and end time. every row is returned as twice multiplied.

Answer (score 1):

There are several things you can do to improve your query.

**Indexes**

It seems that you should have indexes defined on a_imei and b_imei.  Perhaps you also would want to include call start and end times in those indexes as well, this depends.

**Specify columns**

Don't use `select *`, instead specify the list of columns you want to return.

```
select
    a_imei_number,
    b_imei_number,
    call_start_time,
    call_end_time
```

**Proper Join**

This depends on exactly what you are looking for in results.  If you want to report on all possible duplicates, you would structure it one way.

```
select c2.a_imei, c2.b_imei, c2.call_start_time, c2.call_end_time
from (select c.a_imei, c.b_imei, c.call_start_time, c.call_end_time
      from calls c
      where c.a_imei = c.b_imei
     ) cbase join
     calls c2
     on cbase.call_start_time between c2.call_start_time and c2.call_end_time;
```

If you have a known `imei_number` and want to search for it, the query would be structured differently.

```
select c2.a_imei, c2.b_imei, c2.call_start_time, c2.call_end_time
from (select c.a_imei, c.b_imei, c.call_start_time, c.call_end_time
      from calls c
      where c.a_imei = 1234 or c.b_imei = 1234
     ) cbase join
     calls c2
     on cbase.call_start_time between c2.call_start_time and c2.call_end_time;
```

Comment: it is returning all rows because every calls' start time is between their own start time and end time. every row is returned as twice multiplied.